# Create browser like back/forward button in nextjs

Tags: next.js

How do you create a back/forward(similar to browser) button in nextjs?

I have tried using

```
const router = useRouter()

router.back() // for back button

// but how about for front button?
// basically this'll only be enabled once the back button has been clicked, pretty much like how back/forward button works in the browser
```

Comment: Why not simply use the browser's built-in back/forward? After all, next is used to make web pages.

Comment: browser's back button renders you back to the previous URL and that URL could be outside the website. i want back button to be deactivated if router.back() is planning to send me outside the website. Pretty much like how back/forward button works in spotify web player

Comment: "that URL could be outside the website" - The issue with trying to block this behaviour is that you can't. Unless you operate that site and know the user came to you, the user can click the back button and exit.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried simply using `window.history.forward()`?

Behind the scenes, `router.back()` executes `window.history.back()`

Comment: The answer is not relevant. The question is about a specific framework nextjs. If you want  some more clarification then please post in comment instead giving answer. Thanks.